# Scala: Generic Implicit class

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to catch the Type from the class I'm implicitly inferring:

```
case class ToGet(key: String)

class Builder[T <: AnyRef] {

  def get(key: String)(implicit mf: Manifest[T]): ToGet = {
    ToGet(key)
  }
}

object Builder {

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  implicit class ToGetImplicits(obj: ToGet) {
    def future[T <: AnyRef]()(implicit mf: Manifest[T]): Future[Option[T]] = ???
  }
}
```

When I create an instance and call the future above, it returns `Future[Option[Nothing]]`.

Is it possible to get the type here or what should a good way to design that?

**EDIT**

e.g:

```
val obj = new Builder[String]
obj.get("myKey").future() //this returns a Future[Option[Nothing]]
```

**EDIT 2**

Added ToGet definition

Comment: Where's the definition of `ToGet`?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco I have updated the thread

Comment: There appears to be no connection between the `T` given to `Builder` and the `T` given as a type param to the `future` method. The `future` infers `Nothing` because that's the best it can do with that it is given. More code may yield a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.get("myKey")` returns a `ToGet`. At this point, the manifest was provided and ignored. All we have now is a `ToGet`.

Now the `future` call pimped on the `ToGet` has no type information it can use, so it infers `Nothing`.

Depending on the intent of the code, you might want to pass the manifest as an implicit parameter to the `ToGet` class:

```
case class ToGet [T] (key: String)(implicit val mf: Manifest[T])
```

And now your implicit class:

```
implicit class ToGetImplicits[T](obj: ToGet[T]) {
  def future(): Future[Option[T]] = {
    // you can access obj.mf here for the manifest
    ???
  }
}
```

The thing is: *something* has to carry the type information through.

Comment: great, it was hard to me to figure out how to carry it... now it's clear

Comment: I _think_ this might be what is going on with what I have in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475447/custom-dsl-by-extending-gatling-how-to-scala potentially? Any chance you could take a quick gander, @Alvaro?