# Custom DSL by extending Gatling: How to Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, gatling, scala-gatling

We're using Gatling to load test our application (and it works great). We're  attempting to DRY up some of the code by making composable extensions on the Gatling classes (like `ScenarioBuilder` / `ChainBuilder` / etc. found in [`io.gatling.core.structure`](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/tree/master/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/structure)).

Here is an example of one of our scenarios:

```java
val scn = scenario("Whatever")
  .exec(Authentication.FeederLogin(userCsvFile, password))
  .exec(User.ExtractId(User.SignIn()))
  .exec(FindPeople(50, "personIds"))

  // SPA load
  .exec(User.FetchLandingPageFor("${userId}"))

  .during(durationSeconds.seconds) {
    pace(3.seconds, 8.seconds)
      .exec(Person.Search("${personIds.random()}"))
      .pause(3.seconds, 10.seconds)

      // start the upload
      .exec(Upload.create())
  }
```

What we'd *like* to do is start to make some of that composable so we can re-use them in other scenarios. Something like this:

```java
val scn = scenario("Whatever")
  .login()

  .during(durationSeconds.seconds) {
    pace(3.seconds, 8.seconds)
      .uploadFor("${personIds.random()}")
  }

// ...

object WhateverScenarios {
  implicit class ScenarioBuilderWithWhatevers(b: ScenarioBuilder) {

    def login() : ScenarioBuilder = {
      b.exec(Authentication.FeederLogin(userCsvFile, password))
      .exec(User.ExtractId(User.SignIn()))
      .exec(FindPeople(50, "personIds"))
    }

    def uploadFor(whom : String) : ScenarioBuilder {
      b.exec(Person.Search("${personIds.random()}"))
      .pause(3.seconds, 10.seconds)

      // start the upload
      .exec(Upload.create())
    }
  }
}
```

Full disclosure; I'm not super familiar with Scala. This works, but the problem is in the `uploadFor` in that at that point it's working with a `ChainBuilder` vs. a `ScenarioBuilder`.

I thought

> *Oh, simple! Just use generics!*

Except I cannot get it to work :( It *looks* like most of these [`extend StructureBuilder[T]`](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/structure/ChainBuilder.scala) but I cannot seem to get a generic definition defined where I can use my `WhateverScenarios` in *any* context of a `StructureBuilder[T]`.

Thanks in advance for any information that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get past my issue, but I'm not entirely sure why I had to do this. What fixed my issue is the following:

```java
object WhateverScenarios {
  implicit class StructureBuilderWithWhatevers[B <: io.gatling.core.structure.StructureBuilder[B]](b: B) {

    def login() : B = {
      b.exec(Authentication.FeederLogin(userCsvFile, password))
      .exec(User.ExtractId(User.SignIn()))
      .exec(FindPeople(50, "personIds"))
    }

    def uploadFor(whom : String) : ScenarioBuilder {
      b.exec(Person.Search("${personIds.random()}"))
      .pause(3.seconds, 10.seconds)

      // start the upload
      .exec(Upload.create())
    }
  }
}
```

The thing that was throwing me for a loop, was *originally* I tried to define it like this:

```
object WhateverScenarios {
  implicit class StructureBuilderWithWhatevers[B <: StructureBuilder[B]](b: B) {
  // ...
}
```

But when I did that, it didn't recognize `login` or `uploadFor` as being part of either `ScenarioBuilder` or `ChainBuilder`. Not sure why, but I had the specify the fully qualified package name for it to work ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

## Edit

Turns out that the fully qualified package name was some weird artifact that I had on my machine. Doing a `./gradlew clean` fixed the issue and I no longer have to use the fully qualified path name.